# How to calculate a Confidence Interval using numpy.percentile() in Python

Tags: python, numpy, confidence-interval, percentile

A homework question asked me to calculate a confidence interval for a mean. When I did it the traditional method and with numpy.percentile() -- I got different answers.

I think that I may be misunderstanding how or when to use np.percentile(). My two questions are:
1. Am I using it wrong -- wrong inputs, etc.
2. Am I using it in the wrong place - should use for bootstrap CIs and not conventional methods?

I've calculated the CI by the traditional formula and np.percentile()

```py
price = np.random.normal(11427, 5845, 30)
# u = mean of orginal vector
# s = std of original vector
print(price)
```

[14209.99205723  7793.06283131 10403.87407888 10910.59681669
 14427.87437741  4426.8122023  13890.22030853  5652.39284669
 22436.9686157   9591.28194843 15543.24262609 11951.15170839
 16242.64433138  3673.40741792 18962.90840397 11320.92073514
 12984.61905211  8716.97883291 15539.80873528 19324.24734807
 12507.9268783  11226.36772026  8869.27092532  9117.52393498
 11786.21064418 11273.61893921 17093.20022578 10163.75037277
 13962.10004709 17094.70579814]

```py
x_bar = np.mean(price) # mean of vector
s = np.std(price) # std of vector
n = len(price) # number of obs
z = 1.96 # for a 95% CI

lower = x_bar - (z * (s/math.sqrt(n)))
upper = x_bar + (z * (s/math.sqrt(n)))
med = np.median(price)

print(lower, med, upper)
```

10838.458908888499 11868.68117628698 13901.386475143861

```py
np.percentile(price, [2.5, 50, 97.5])
```

[ 4219.6258866  11868.68117629 20180.24569667]

```py
ss.scoreatpercentile(price, [2.5, 50, 97.5])
```

[ 4219.6258866  11868.68117629 20180.24569667]

I would expect the lower, med and upper to equal the output of np.percentile().

While the median values are the same -- the upper and lower are quite a bit off of each other.

Moreover, scipy.stats.percentile gives the same output as numpy.percentile.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Edited to show the price vector.

Comment: could you please provide the array `price`?

Comment: @kmario23 I edited it to 'show' the price array. It was a column from a DF, but I just made a random normal vector with its parameters. The error is still there and still quite large. Any help would be great!

Comment: You will get a much better explanation of confidence interval vs percentile than I can give over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A confidence interval and a percentile are not the same thing. The formulas for the two things are very different

The number of samples you have is going to affect your confidence interval, but won't change (much) the percentiles.

e.g.

```
price = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)
print (np.percentile(price, [2.5, 50, 97.5])
```

gives

```
[-1.97681778  0.01808908  1.93659551]
```

and

```
price = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100000000)
print (np.percentile(price, [2.5, 50, 97.5]))
```

gives pretty much the same:

```
[-1.96012643  9.82108813e-05  1.96030460]
```

But running your CI calculation code, if you increase the number of samples massively, your confidence interval will shrink - because you are now 95% confident that the mean of the distribution lies within a smaller range.

Using the same 2 price arrays (mean=0, sd =1) with 10 samples and 10,000 samples your results are:

```
-0.5051688819759096 0.17504324224822834 0.744716862363091 # 10 samples
-0.02645090158517636 -0.006759616493022626 0.012353106820212557 # 10000 samples
```

As you can see, CI is much smaller with more samples (as you would expect, given the formula for CI!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I was confusing percentile with CI. Face palm.

Thanks again